# How to run AWS SDK with credentials from variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

I used environment variables before and it worked fine.

Now I am migrating my config variables into a single file and I have AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID variables containing respective values that are loaded from this file.

I tried this code but receiving an error:

```
creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials("123", conf.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, conf.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Credentials: creds})
```

Here is the error

> InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.

How do I properly inject my keys into the aws sdk calls?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try re-ordering your args so that ACCESS_KEY is the 1st param and SECRET_KEY is the second:

```
creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(conf.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, conf.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, "")
```

Try adding the region as well:

```
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region:      aws.String("us-west-2"),
    Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(conf.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, conf.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, ""),
})
```

Comment: I got `InvalidToken: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.` I think we should generate the token first, is it correct? @dave-maple

Comment: Didn't realize NewStaticCredentials third argument could be an empty string! Nor, if I indeed needed to provide a 'token', what that actually means in the context of that method or how to acquire a token. The docs leave _a lot_ to be desired.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can just temporaly set Environment variables.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)

const (
    AccessKeyId     = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    SecretAccessKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    Region          = "eu-west-1"
    Bucket          = "XXXXX-XXXX-XXX"
)

func main() {
    os.Setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",     AccessKeyId)
    os.Setenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", SecretAccessKey)

    filename := os.Args[1]

    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to open file", filename, err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    conf := aws.Config{Region: aws.String(Region)}
    sess := session.New(&conf)

    svc := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

    fmt.Println("Uploading file to S3...")
    result, err := svc.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(Bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(filepath.Base(filename)),
        Body:   file,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Additionally, if you hadn't known, the SDK allows for the use of the shared config under `.aws/config`. You can put your values in there and then set the environment variable `AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG` to a truthy value to load the shared config. An example shared config would look like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKID
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET
```

Then running:

```
AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=true go run main.go
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `creds` variable to the `aws.Config` struct to set the AWS credentials for the S3 session.

> You need to import the github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials package.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

func main() {
    accessKey := "ACCESS"
    secretKey := "SECRET"
    creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials(accessKey, secretKey, "")

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Credentials: creds,
        Endpoint:    aws.String("ENDPOINT"),
        Region:      aws.String("REGION"),
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    svc := s3.New(sess)

    bucketName := "ramingotestsdk"

    _, err = svc.CreateBucket(&s3.CreateBucketInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Bucket %s created\n", bucketName)
}
```

### OUTPUT:

```bash
Bucket ramingotestsdk created
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have the option to utilize your configurations within an aws.Credentials struct, as demonstrated in the code snippet below.

```
package services

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "ldapmng/config"
    "time"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/directoryservice"
)

type AwsService struct {
    Ds *directoryservice.Client
}

func NewAwsService(ctx context.Context) (*AwsService, error) {

    awsService := &AwsService{}

    settings, _ := config.LoadSettings()

    awsSessionExpiration, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00", settings.AwsSessionExpiration)

    creds := aws.Credentials{
        AccessKeyID:     settings.AwsAccessKeyId,
        SecretAccessKey: settings.AwsSecretAccessKey,
        SessionToken:    settings.AwsSessionToken,
        // Source:          ,
        // CanExpire:       false,
        Expires: awsSessionExpiration,
    }

    credsProvider := credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider{
        Value: creds,
    }

    cfg := aws.Config{
        Region:      settings.AwsRegion,
        Credentials: credsProvider,
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error loading AWS configuration:", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    awsService.Ds = directoryservice.NewFromConfig(cfg)

    return awsService, nil
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Connect your sdk client using this generic service

```
var awsSession *session.Session

func init() {
    initializeAwsSession()
}


func initializeAwsSession() {
    awsSession = session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String("ap-southeast-1"),
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials("YOUR_ACCESS_KEY","YOUR SECRET_KEY", ""),
    }))
}
```