# How to run AWS SDK version 2 with credentials from variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-iam, aws-sdk-go

My question is the same as this other question: [How to run AWS SDK with credentials from variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544554/how-to-run-aws-sdk-with-credentials-from-variables) but I am using SDK version 2 which no longer uses Session (if I understand correctly).

So, I am creating a new client, and I have the credentials as variables. I need to use the IAM service. Here is the function:

```
func getIAMClient(ctx context.Context) (*iam.Client, error) {
    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx, config.WithRegion("no-region"))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err)
    }

    cfg.HTTPClient, err = getHTTPClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return iam.NewFromConfig(cfg), nil
}
```

Different users will use the app at the same time, so I can't just use ENV files, but I haven't been able to find a documentation page explaining how to pass these credentials to my Client. Any support will be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved with the [StaticCredentialsProvider](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials#StaticCredentialsProvider) as described in [section "Static Credentials" of the AWS SDK for Go V2 documentation](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/configuring-sdk/#static-credentials):

```
cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(ctx, config.WithCredentialsProvider(credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider("AKID", "SECRET_KEY", "TOKEN")))
```

Comment: Yes, I have the information in variables, they're not hardcoded. This solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

To init configs from *runtime* variables, it's fine to use [`credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/credentials#NewStaticCredentialsProvider):

```
staticProvider := credentials.NewStaticCredentialsProvider(
    accessKey, 
    secretKey, 
    sessionToken,
)
cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(
    context.Background(), 
    config.WithCredentialsProvider(staticProvider),
)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
client := iam.New(cfg)
```

However the AWS SDK documentation correctly [reminds](https://aws.github.io/aws-sdk-go-v2/docs/configuring-sdk/#static-credentials) you that:

> Do not embed credentials inside an application. Use this method only for testing purposes.

This is because typically code snippets that use static credentials pass hardcoded strings, which obviously is a security issue. In your case, you are attempting to pass runtime variables, so as long as those are not checked in with your application sources, you should be fine.

---

For the general use case, i.e. *environment* variables, you can use [`external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external#LoadDefaultAWSConfig), which automatically looks for, in this order:

- Environment Variables
- Shared Configuration and Shared Credentials files.

```
// import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external"

    cfg, err := external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig(external.WithRegion(region))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    client := iam.New(cfg)
```

The method under the hood calls [`external.NewEnvConfig`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external#NewEnvConfig) which tries to fetch credentials from the environment variables:

- `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` or `AWS_SECRET_KEY`
- `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` or `AWS_ACCESS_KEY`

More details about the read priority of the env vars is given in [`EnvConfig`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external#EnvConfig) documentation.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was precisely how to pass credentials manually and not have the SDK fetch them from environment or configuration files.

Comment: @CamiloUrán yes, TBH at first I misunderstood your question. However the term "variable" in your title may be found by people who look for "environment" variables. So I added the solution to your specific problem to my answer, and left the general part for other use cases

Comment: I see! Thanks, like you said, the general case is always useful too.